# React native fetch from URL every X seconds

Tags: react-native

In the page I have two things to do, first I fetch some content from API and display it. After that, I will fetch another API every 5 seconds to see whether the status of the content displayed has been changed or not.

In my `MyScreen.js`

```
const MyScreen = props => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const onConfirmHandler = async () => {
        try {
            //get content from API and display on the screen
            const response1 = await dispatch(action1(param1,param2));
            if(response1==='success'){
                // I want to check the result of response2 every 5 seconds, how can I do this?
                const response2 = await dispatch(action2(param3));
            }
        }catch {...}
    }

    return (
        <Button title='confirm' onPress={onConfirmHandler}}>
    )
}
```

The actions I fetch the API in `actions.js`:

```
export default action1 = (param1,param2) ={
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        // To call the API, I need to used token I got when login
        let = getState().login.token;
        const response = await fetch(url,body);
        const resData = await response.json();
        if (resData==='success'){
            return param3
        }
}

export default action2 = (param3) ={
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        // To call the API, I need to used token I got when login
        let = getState().login.token;
        const response = await fetch(url,body);
        const resData = await response.json();
        if (resData==='success'){
            // if the content status changed, I change the view in MyScreen.js
            return 'changed';
        }
}
```

Comment: A simple setInterval would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I have also met this problem already. Here you can't use the timeout function. Instead, you can use [react-native-socketio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-socketio) or [react-native-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch) packages. I prefer react-native-background-fetch. So you can fetch results at a specific interval and update the state on change of content.